# Dealing with 'No such element exception' w/ Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select (if present) a month of the year in a dropdown list, where (month) can be any string from 'January' to 'December' (these are also the elements on the dropdown list)
 But not every month is necessarily on the list.

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selectMonth")).select_by_visible_text("%s" % (month))
```

"selectMonth" is the id of the list, and the visible text is named according to the month. I have created a loop where I select each month from January to December, but I'm having problems when the month isn't on the list (NoSuchElementException).

How do I check if the month is on the dropdown list before trying to select it?

There's some good information about NoSuchElementException in this other post ([Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443)), but I couldn't use it to solve my problem. It's similar, but not the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for what you're trying. I am adding the text of each month available in the dropdown to a list, that it will check against before trying to select the current month in the loop.

```
MonthSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selectMonth"))
DropDownOptions = []
# seems like you have the string of each month in a list/array already so I will refer to that
for option in MonthSelect.options: DropDownOptions.append(option.text)
for month in MonthList:
    if month in DropDownOptions:
        MonthSelect.select_by_visible_text("%s" % (month))
```

---

Edit:

As @Bob pointed out, you could also catch the `Exception` as so:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selectMonth")).select_by_visible_text("%s" % (month))
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

This way you can try every month, but just pass the months that are not present.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the element is there you can also consider to assume it is [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). In other words just try to select the thing, and catch the `NoSuchElementException` if it fails.